# Who is responsible for generating public key during secure communication?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

This must be easy but I am getting a little confused.
Say, facebook.com, it has a certificate which is signed by an intermediary CA.

1. Who generated that public key that I can see in facebook certificate? Is it generated by Facebook or that intermediary CA?
2. Does the public key change often or it gets modified only when the certificate expires?

Comment: As layman I would be interested to know, since "Who" in the title line is now identified with "Facebook" (see answer), what kind of concrete legal "responsibility" does it actually take or promise to take in case of eventual problems.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen in this question "Who" means "Who, the Certificate Requestor or the Certificate Authority?" where "Facebook" is the *example* used of a Certificate Requestor.  In general, the CA is responsible for verifying the identity of the requestor before granting the certificate to them.  However, "concrete legal responsibility" is a complex question (encompassing "for what? when? where? and accused by whom?") that can't really be answered on Security.SE in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*"Facebook" here is just "an example of someone that wants a certificate."  There is no inherent special Facebookness about this situation.*]

> Who generated that public key that I can see in facebook certificate?
>   Is it generated by Facebook or that intermediary CA?

1. Facebook generates the "keypair" consisting of a public key and a private key.
2. Facebook then generates a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) which includes the public key, and send the CSR along to the CA.
3. The CA signs the public key based on that request and returns the signed public key (the "certificate") to Facebook.
4. Facebook installs the private key and the certificate on their web server, and you see that signed certificate when you ask your browser to show you the security of the connection.

> Does the public key change often or it gets modified only when the
>   certificate expires?

Ideally it changes whenever the certificate expires - one *could* submit a new CSR using the old keypair and get a new certificate for the old public key, but that would defeat the purpose of expiring certificates, which is to ensure key turnover.

You should also be aware that many modern ciphers used with TLS, like the ECDHE variants, validate the connection using the presented public key (certificate) as described, but then spin up a new ("ephemeral") keypair on the fly and use that to actually protect the encryption.  So the certificate you see in the web browser is not the actual certificate used to protect data, and the certificate used to protect data has an exceedingly short lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for an exact answer.   
I have a question regarding public key pinning then if I can ask here. So this public key which is generated by facebook is the only key that they own. Is this key used to public key pinning? As other keys might change which is not in their control. But if it happens, then the last case that you mentioned here regarding "spin up a new(ephemeral) keypair" , how will public key pinning take place?.

Comment: @one The cert is used to authenticate the server during the TLS negotiation process, and that's what you'd pin to.  Any ephemeral certs spun up to encrypt the actual data _as negotiated_ are used for encryption, not authentication; you'd not want to pin to them, nor will you find pinning software that even tries to.